# React to iphone headphone's next button (doubleclick) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I would like to react on double and triple clicks on iphone headphones from my weppage. Is there an Safari api for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly there is no support for that at safari api level, however the video that you are playing will play and pause as it would do in the normal cases, but you cant capture that event at JS level